# how to count number of file with a matching pattern using python

Tags: python

**Code:**

```py
import os, glob
HOME_FOLDER = 'path_to_directory'
pattern = '*2019*'
f = os.listdir(HOME_FOLDER)
c = 0;
for root, dirs, files in sorted(os.walk(HOME_FOLDER)):
    for file in files:
        if glob.fnmatch.fnmatch(file, pattern):
            c+=1
       
for name in f:
     print("Dir with ID", name, "has", c, "files of 2019")
```

**Output:**

```
Dir with ID 69 has 10 files of 2019
Dir with ID 10 has 10 files of 2019
Dir with ID 1 has 10 files of 2019
Dir with ID 2 has 10 files of 2019
Dir with ID 13 has 10 files of 2019
```

The output gives only the total number of files. I want to have the number of files with the matching pattern.

Like this:

```
Dir with ID 20 has 3 files of 2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
import pathlib

HOME_FOLDER = pathlib.Path('path_to_directory')
PATTERN = "*2019*"

for item in HOME_FOLDER.iterdir():
    if item.is_dir():
        matching_files = len(list([f for f in item.glob(f"**/{PATTERN}") if f.is_file()]))
        print("Dir with ID", item.name, "has", matching_files, "files of 2019")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```py
c = 0
for root, dirs, files in sorted(os.walk(HOME_FOLDER)):
    c += len([file for file in files if ('2019' in file)])
```

Or, in a single line with `list-comprehension`:

```py
sum([
    len([file for file in files if ('2019' in file)]) 
    for root, dirs, files in sorted(os.walk(HOME_FOLDER))
]
```

### Common Code

You don't need to use `glob` for this purpose; `os.walk` would suffice alone.

```py
import os
HOME_FOLDER = 'path_to_directory'
pattern = '2019' # note I am not using *2019*
f = os.listdir(HOME_FOLDER)
```